API works on Local, but not on the server with Laravel
It gives me this error when I run it on the server and not locally. I thought it might be something about the API with HTTPS, but I'm not too sure

Error: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to url port 80: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://url/stock/

The request:
    private function connectToAPI ($headers, $url) {
       try {
           $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($url);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
           return false;
    }

    if (!isset($response) || $response->status() != 200) {
        Log::error("Error: " . $response->body());
        return false;
    }

    return $response;
}

Any idea what the error could be?

You may need to contact your host about this issue, especially since it works locally. It'a "connection timed out", which could be a firewall, a connection block, or something else.

What does $url contain? Does your server allow outbound traffic?
